# How to get all the elements between two marker tags?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml like the one below. I want all the elements between start & end self closing marker tags. ignore the rest of the elements. I am trying to do this in XSLT.

```
 <catalog>
 <cd>
    <start/>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
 </cd>
 <end/>
 </catalog>
```

Comment: well, please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is quite straightforward:

- define `rng1` variable containing elements following `start`
  (*following* axis),
- define `rng2` variable containing elements preceding `end`
  (*preceding* axis),
- apply templates to the intersection of these 2 elemen sets.

But to get a properly formed XML output, the template must generate
an "envelope" e.g. `root` element and then generate what was said inside it.

Another detail: As you don't know exact XPaths to both `start` and `end`,
the XSLT code must specify them starting from `//`.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:variable name="rng1" select="//start/following::*"/>
      <xsl:variable name="rng2" select="//end/preceding::*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$rng1 intersect $rng2"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```